# How do I set up a Grunt task that watches files and continually runs the tests every time a file changes

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman

My starting point is the [Yeoman Backbone Generator](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-backbone). I have it set up and running correctly.

Instead of having to manually run `grunt test` every time I want to test, I'd rather have it running the tests automatically every time a file changes.

I want to be still be able to run `grunt server` for all the awesomeness it currently give me.  Is there a way to add Continuous Integration (is that the right word? I'm kind of new to that)  to that grunt task?

Or would it be better to not touch `grunt server` and essentially eliminate `grunt test` and replace it with something that runs in a separate terminal like Testem or Karma.

Or could something like Testem or Karma be used through a grunt task without losing useful functionality.

Answer (score 1):

When you use the generator, it should have created a Gruntfile with a [watch task](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch).

With a newly generated project, the server task has runs the `watch` task:

```
grunt.registerTask('server', function (target) {
    if (target === 'dist') {
        return grunt.task.run(['build', 'open', 'connect:dist:keepalive']);
    } else if (target === 'test') {
        return grunt.task.run([
            'clean:server',
            'coffee',
            'createDefaultTemplate',
            'jst',
            'compass:server',
            'connect:test:keepalive'
        ]);
    }

    grunt.task.run([
        'clean:server',
        'coffee:dist',
        'createDefaultTemplate',
        'jst',
        'compass:server',
        'connect:livereload',
        'open',
        'watch'    // <==== Here
    ]);
});
```

`Watch` has the ability to run tasks when files are updated.  Add your test task there.

Sample `watch` config generated by yo backbone:

```
watch: {
    options: {
        nospawn: true
    },
    coffee: {
        files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.coffee'],
        tasks: ['coffee:dist']
    },
    coffeeTest: {
        files: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.coffee'],
        tasks: ['coffee:test']
    },
    compass: {
        files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}'],
        tasks: ['compass']
    },
    livereload: {
        options: {
            livereload: LIVERELOAD_PORT
        },
        files: [
            '<%= yeoman.app %>/*.html',
            '{.tmp,<%= yeoman.app %>}/styles/{,*/}*.css',
            '{.tmp,<%= yeoman.app %>}/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
            '<%= yeoman.app %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp}'
        ]
    },
    jst: {
        files: [
            '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/templates/*.ejs'
        ],
        tasks: ['jst']
    }
}
```

Say you ran the backbone generator to use Mocha as the test framework.

You would have these sections in your `Gruntfile.js`:

Under `connect` configure a port that is different from the app port of 9000:

```
connect: {
    …
    test: {
        options: {
            port: 9090,  // <== Add this here
            middleware: function (connect) {
                return [
                    mountFolder(connect, '.tmp'),
                    mountFolder(connect, 'test'),
                    mountFolder(connect, yeomanConfig.app)
                ];
            }
        }
    },
    …
},
```

Under the Mocha configuration change the port that it uses to reference `connect.test.options.port`:

```
    mocha: {
        all: {
            options: {
                run: true,
/* change ==>*/ urls: ['http://localhost:<%= connect.test.options.port %>/index.html']
            }
        }
    },
```

As registered Tasks:

```
grunt.registerTask('test', [
    'clean:server',
    'coffee',
    'createDefaultTemplate',
    'jst',
    'compass',
    'connect:test',
    'mocha'
]);
```

Under `watch` add a test target - something like this:

```
    test: {
        files: [
            '<%= yeoman.app %>/*.html',
            '{.tmp,<%= yeoman.app %>}/styles/{,*/}*.css',
            '{.tmp,<%= yeoman.app %>}/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
            '<%= yeoman.app %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp}'
        ],
        tasks: ['test']
    }
```

With those changes, anytime a file changes that matches the `test.files` glob, the `test` task will be run.

The exact steps to get this working for your code will depend on the test framework and grunt plugins you've chosen.  In addition to the [Getting Started - installing plugins](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/wiki/Getting-started#installing-grunt-and-gruntplugins) and [Configuring Tasks](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/wiki/Configuring-tasks) guides, look through your test plugin documentation to ensure you have a good understanding of how its specific configuration works.

You did mention two test frameworks in your answer.  I haven't used either of these but both have grunt plugins available.

- [Karma plugins](http://gruntjs.com/plugins/karma)
- [Testem plugin](http://gruntjs.com/plugins/testem)

If these general steps still don't help, it would be helpful if you could provide more specifics about your project including your `Gruntfile.js`, test framework of choice, what you have tried and errors/failures you are seeing.

Comment: Right, I have that default setup working. What do I need to change to have it continuously running tests on `grunt server`

Comment: When you run `grunt server` it will run all of its dependent tasks including the `watch` task which, in turn will run all of its tasks including any test task you may have configured.  I'll try to update my answer to make it more clear.